# robot-framework error:Message: element not interactable: ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am a new in python. Trying to delete a row from a table automatically using robot-framework. Table contained 3 visible rows. Here is my code

```
    *** Settings ***
    #Test Teardown     Close Browser
    Library  SeleniumLibrary
    Library  Stringpip
    
    *** Variables ***
    
    ${Reps_Menu_Button}  xpath=//div[@data-testid='carrier-reps-list']//div[@data-cellheader='Menu']/button
    ${reps_Delete_Button}   xpath=//reach-portal[13]//div[.='Delete']
    ${Save_Carrier_Button}  xpath=//button[.='Save Carrier']
    ${Success_Toast}  xpath=//div[@class='Toastify__toast Toastify__toast--success']
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    #Delete Reps :
    
      wait until element is visible  ${reps_menu_button}
      click element  ${reps_menu_button}
      click element  ${reps_delete_button}
      handle alert  ACCEPT
      click element  ${save_carrier_button}
      wait until element is not visible  ${success_toast}
```

Please guide me here. Whether I am missing anything? or doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML code from the application you're automating?

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables you created. Variable names are case sensitive.